# I cant find the problem why my discord bot doesnt work(maybe intents)?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Here is the code I am testing and there are no errors if i compile it?

```
const {
  Client,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  EmbedBuilder,
  PermissionsBitfield,
  Permissions,
} = require("discord.js");

const prefix = ">";

//Intents Huren
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});

//Message Reaction

client.on("messagCreate", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  //message Array

  const messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  const argument = messageArray.slice(1);
  const cmd = messageArray[0];

  //test Command
  if (command === "test") {
    message.channel.send("Bot is working!");
  }
});

//Client is Ready
client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot Ready");
});

client.login("");
```

Comment: You probably forgot to enable them in the Discord developer console as well

Comment: you've misspelled `messageCreate`.

Answer (score -3):

There is no `messagCreate` event. Please change it to `messageCreate` then it should work.